# send mail with attachment ruby

Tags: ruby, email, actionmailer

I want send mail with an attachment file. I need have then format body text in html, when configure the format, the file attachment sent bad in the mail.

My code using actionMailer:

```
#require 'mail'

class MyMail < ActionMailer::Base
  default :from => 'cristian.gonzalez@powersystem.com.ar'          

  def send_mail(user,pdffile_name,pdffile_name_second,pdffile_name_thir,htmlfile_name)

    #sendgrid_unique_args :key1 => user.id
    email_with_name = "#{user.send_user} <#{user.mail_address}>"
    #Adjuntar el archivo   1
    unless pdffile_name.nil?
      filename = user.first_attachment.partition("/")[2]    
      attachments[filename] = File.open(pdffile_name, 'rb', &:read)          
    end
    mail :to => 'cdgonzalez82@gmail.com',
         :subject = user.mail_subject, 
         :content_type = 'text/html; charset=UTF-8',
         :email.body = user.mail_body

  end
end
```

Any help please???

Comment: what do you mean, sent bad?  What errors, or results do you get?

Comment: the mail have the file attachment in format incorrect.